# Is it secure to save data to firebase cloud firestore like this (see below)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase cloud firestore and I want to create a way users can see simple data (like a quiz result or score) online. I generate a random code and use it as the title of a document containing the data in firstore. I give the user the code and you can enter it on a webpage to see your data (without any sign in).

Is this secure?

What should the firebase cloud firestore rules be?
(Currently I allow all writes and reads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **can** be secure if you do it carefully. This is similar to the [unguessable photo URLs](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/07/googles_unguess.html) which Google uses on Google Photos.

A few things:

- **NEVER** allow all reads and writes. This means anyone in the world can delete all of your data at any time.  At a minimum, block write access.
- If you have `allow read` rules on these documents, split them up into `allow get` and `allow list`.  You do want to allow anyone who knows the URL to do a `get()` but you probably want to disable `list` since that would allow someone to download the list of all the document IDs and iterate through them.  [More information here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Comment: How should I handle writes? (maybe so that a person can only write what he/she created)

Comment: For writes you probably want some sort of authentication.  Only writing records that you created is a good start.

Comment: I tried a few things but they did not work as expected, how do I only allow writes to documents created by the same person/device? (without user accounts)

Comment: `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
   allow get: if true;
    allow list: if false;
    allow write: if true;
  }
  }
}` These are my rules at the moment

Comment: but what about when you want to update one field? From the front end you could send whatever you want right?